# Por qué el codigo PHP no se ve a simple vista en una web como si lo hace javascript

Tags: php

Al hacer pruebas con PHP noté que este no se muestra como lo hace cualquier otro lenguaje de programación en *inspeccionar elemento* o en *ver código fuente* ¿Acaso PHP es tan seguro y díficil de obtener? o alguien podría obtener las instrucciones de un sitio web...

```
<?php 

echo "<h1>¡Hello World!</h1>";

?>
```

Comment: En realidad es porque PHP es un lenguaje enfocado a desarrollar scripts del lado del servidor. Este luego enviará un html que puede ver el cliente. Puedes [pasar por acá](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro-whatis.php) para darte una idea. Pero básicamente necesitas acceso a tu servidor para saber qué tipo de código se está ejecutando y la información que se envía.

Comment: Por que PHP se interpreta en el servidor y no en el navegador, no tiene que ver con si es seguro o no, de hecho el único lenguaje **de programación** del que podrás observar su código fuente en el navegador será de JavaScript

Comment: *Al hacer pruebas con PHP noté que este no se muestra como lo hace cualquier otro lenguaje de programación en inspeccionar elemento o en ver código fuente* ... Si PHP se pudiera inspeccionar como sí se puede hacer con el **código fuente HTML** sería un desastre. Imagina que en PHP se hace visible información tan delicada como contraseñas, números de tarjeta de crédito y otras. Imagina ahora que eso pueda verse tan fácilmente y/o ser cambiado o manipulado como podría hacerse con tanta facilidad con contenido del lado del cliente. Sería una catástrofe.

Answer (score 0):

Trataré de explicarte, de forma tal, que me entiendas los más posible, sin tener otros aspectos en cuenta.

A pesar de que ambas tecnologías son usadas intensamente en el desarrollo web, se ocupan de partes diferentes del ecosistema de una página web .

**Javascript** es un lenguaje de programación que funciona en el lado del cliente. Esto quiere decir que al igual que pasa con HTML y CSS, en el momento en que estás ejecutando el código Javascript, dicho código está descargado en tu ordenador. Por tanto, tu vas a poder examinarlo, e incluso copiarlo y modificarlo (podrás modificar el código que te has descargado).
Este lenguaje se ejecuta en el navegador, así que depende del navegador (firefox, chrome, internet explorer, etc) que este código se ejecute correctamente.

**PHP** es un lenguaje de programación del lado del servidor. Por tanto, salvo que seamos los propietarios de la página y tengamos acceso al servidor, no vamos a poder ver el código PHP de la página. Nosotros como usuarios de una web, no tenemos acceso a su código PHP.

Ya que PHP es un lenguaje del lado del servidor, se ocupa de las funcionalidades que tienen que ver con el servidor. Con PHP puedes mandar un mail, acceder a la base de datos, etc.

Fuente: https://pablomonteserin.com/diferencias-javascript-php/

Comment: Yo ampliaría indicando que Javascript si bien lo interpreta el navegador, también es posible que funcione en el servidor con NodeJS por tanto tareas como envío de emails que mencionas al final y acceso a bd también son posibles con esta última tecnología que menciono

Comment: Claro que sí.  Totalmente de acuerdo. Es como dije al principio. Lo más básico posible para lograr una mejor comprensión a los que aún no tiene ese conocimiento avanzado.

Answer (score 0):

Adicional a lo expresado en comentarios y respuestas.

Todo, o buena parte, está en la arquitectura: Cliente-Servidor. Imagina cualquier escenario de la vida (no virtual) en el que vas como cliente a utilizar un servicio. Hay cosas, procesos, que son transparentes al cliente y necesariamente los debe realizar el que brinda el servicio, ya sea por seguridad, por la infraestructura requerida, o por los conocimientos para hacerlo.

PHP surgió para hacer la Web dinámica desde el servidor (recordemos que HTML por sí solo no puede cambiar su estructura, es un lenguaje de marcado), y ese proceso de dinamización incluye el manejo de la lógica del negocio que por sus características así lo requiere (demanda de recursos de hardware, seguridad, acceso a otros servicios, etc).

Y aquí hablamos de PHP, pero como ya mencionaban en un comentario, hace años que JavaScript se puede utilizar para lo mismo, también Java, Python, C#, etc. En todos los casos, este código se ejecuta en el servidor y envía los resultados al cliente, bien en forma de HTML o de JSON, o XML. En las dos últimas formas se delga la responsabilidad de la GUI al cliente, total o parcialmente.

Ahora, analiza el siguiente fragmento (simplificado, quizás al absurdo), e imagina todo esto en la PC de todos los usuarios que accedan al sitio:

```
<?php 

if($usuarioLogueado === 'nuevousuario'){
    echo '<a href="banco.com/acceder?usuario=nuevousuario">Entrar a mi cuenta bancaria</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="banco.com/acceder?usuario=eniel.rod">Entrar a mi cuenta bancaria</a>';
}

?>
```